# Depurar archivos mediante el comando pg_archivecleanup

Tags: postgresql, depuración, cluster

Necesito utilizar el comando pg_archivecleanup para depurar el log generado en la ruta /var/lib/postgresql/. Entiendo que este log es derivado de la replicación del cluster, el comando que tengo es el siguiente

```
pg_archievecleanup  -d /var/lib/postgresql/0000000100000034000000E7
```

Pero al ejecutar la siguiente línea no borra nada y arroja el siguiente mensaje: pg_archivecleanup: keeping WAL file "/var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/0000000100000034000000E7" and later

He estado investigando y veo que la depuracion la hace a raiz de un archivo backup. Me pueden asesorar so

Pueden asesorarme sobre la manera en la que se ejecuta, por favor?